# Ajax call returning an error of Status Code: 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a script that loads a page of data. Within the code, I have an ajax call that checks the underlying data table for a change on a column.
If ajax return a JSON response of `1`, then redirect to another page named `override.php`.

If the ajax returns a JSON response of `0`, continue with the script on page "template20.php" and check if ajax return a JSON response of `2`.

If the response is `2`, redirect to another page named `ignage.php`.
Within page "signage.php" I have another script that checks the underlying data table for a change on a column. If the ajax return a JSON response of "0", redirect back to `template20.php`.

The first ajax call marked `//CALL ONE` works fine but the second ajax call marked `//CALL TWO` loads page but returns an error in the browser `console Status Code: 403 Forbidden` when trying to load the image on that page.

**template20.php**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
url: "check_override.php",
success: function(data) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
  if(result == 1) {
    $(function(){
      $("#Header", window.top.document).hide();
    });
    window.location.href = 'override.php'; //CALL ONE
  } else if(result == 2) {
    $(function(){
      $("#Header", window.top.document).hide();
    });
    window.location.href = 'signage.php'; //CALL TWO
  } else {
    $(function(){
      $("#Header", window.top.document).show();
  });
  }
    }
  });
}, 9000);
```

**override.php**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "check_override.php",
success: function(data) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
      if(result == 0) {
        console.log("RESULT = 2");
        $("#Header", window.top.document).show()
        window.location.href = 'template20.php';
      }
    }
  });
},9000);
```

**signage.php**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url: "check_override.php",
    success: function(data) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(data);
      if(result == 0) {
        console.log("RESULT = 2");
        $("#Header", window.top.document).show()
        window.location.href = 'template20.php';
      }
    }
  });
},9000);
```

On the `signage.php` page I have some CSS and one of the classes is:

```
#image {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('<?php echo $ImagePath."". $row_fb['ClientImageName'];?>');
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}
```

and in the body I have:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

I have double-checked the `$ImagePath`, and it is correct. If I load the URL directly to the image in a browser, it works fine.

Comment: I see no reference to any `<img />` in your code, so I have no way of knowing how you get 403 when "trying to load the image"

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  Hi and thanks for looking. I have added more code relating the the signage.php page which displays the image.

Comment: Okay, and can you confirm for me what the rendered HTML(/CSS) is? ie. use View Source on the problem page and look for that `background-image` line. What is the *browser* seeing?

Comment: The source for the background-image is background-image: url('../../../../conf_images/promotions/EXBHX/'); The "id="image" tag in the body displays nothing, i.e empty.

Comment: The console displays the EXBHX is forbidden, the directory does exsist and the permissions are correct.

Comment: I don't think you can put a *directory* as a background image. You need a filename there... It seems like `$row_fb['ClientImageName']` doesn't have the filename you expect it to have?

Comment: Resolved: it was the query, it was not returning the image name. Many thanks for all your time.